# Who is better between netcat and scp in terms of authentication, confidentiality and performance? how

Tags: tcp, wireshark, scp, netcat

I reckon, performance is better in netcat because if the file is large, then scp break down to transfer the file.

Answer (score 3):

netcat:

- doesn't use authentication,
- is unencrypted (traffic is not confidential),

scp:

- works on top of ssh, which uses strong authentication mechanisms,
- is encrypted (traffic is confidential),

scp has more overhead associated with each connection (due to authentication and encryption), and so will most likely lose to netcat in a head-to-head race to transfer a file. But what scp loses in performance, it more than makes up for with its confidentiality and integrity guarantees, as well as ease of use.